# Warning message after creating the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors, natbib

My code as are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}  %ch06 - $\currency$
\usepackage{multirow} %ch10 - table4
\usepackage{amssymb}  %ch12 - \thicksim

\usepackage[round,authoryear,comma,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \chapter*{REFERENCES}%
\markboth{References}{References}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}%
\small\list{}{%
  \leftmargin 1em\itemindent -1em\parsep \z@
    \itemsep\z@%
 }}%
{\endlist}%
\makeatother

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Ahmed and Rogers}{Ahmed and
  Rogers}{1995}]{Ahmed1995}
Ahmed, S. and J.~H. Rogers (1995).
\newblock Government budget deficits and trade deficits: Are present value
  constraints satisfied in long-term data?
\newblock {\em Journal of Monetary Economics\/}~{\em 36\/}(2), 351--374.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina and Ardagna}{Alesina and Ardagna}{1998}]{Ardagna1998}
Alesina, A. and S. Ardagna (1998). Tales of fiscal adjustment. \textit{Economic Policy}~{\em 13\/}(27), 489--585.

%\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Ahmed and Rogers}{Ahmed and
%  Rogers}{1995}]{Ahmed1995}
%Ahmed, S. and J.~H. Rogers (1995).
%\newblock Government budget deficits and trade deficits are present value
%  constraints satisfied in long-term data?
%\newblock {\em Journal of Monetary Economics\/}~{\em 36\/}(2), 351--374.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina and Ardagna}{Alesina and
  Ardagna}{2010}]{Alesina2010}
Alesina, A. and S.~Ardagna (2010).
\newblock Large changes in fiscal policy: Taxes versus spending.
\newblock In {\em Tax Policy and the Economy,} Volume 24, pp.\
  35--68. National Bureau of Economic Research.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina and Ardagna}{Alesina and
  Ardagna}{2013}]{Alesina2013}
Alesina, A. and S.~Ardagna (2013).
\newblock The design of fiscal adjustments.
\newblock {\em Tax Policy and the Economy\/}, Volume 27, pp., 19--68.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Ardagna, and Galasso}{Alesina
  et~al.}{2010}]{Alesina2010b}
Alesina, A., S.~Ardagna, and V.~Galasso (2010).
\newblock The euro and structural reforms.
\newblock In A.~Alesina and F.~Giavazzi (Eds.), {\em Europe and the Euro},
   pp.\  57--98. University of Chicago Press and National Bureau of Economic Research.



\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Ardagna, Perotti, and
  Schiantarelli}{Alesina et~al.}{2002}]{Alesina2002}
Alesina, A., S.~Ardagna, R.~Perotti, and F.~Schiantarelli (2002, June).
\newblock Fiscal policy, profits, and investment.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 92\/}(3), 571--589.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Ardagna, and Trebbi}{Alesina
  et~al.}{2006}]{Alesina2006}
Alesina, A., S.~Ardagna, and F.~Trebbi (2006).
\newblock Who adjusts and when? The political economy of reforms.
\newblock {\em IMF Staff Papers\/}~{\em 53}, 1--49.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Azzalini, Favero, Giavazzi, and
  Miano}{Alesina et~al.}{2016}]{Alesina2016a}
Alesina, A., G.~Azzalini, C.~Favero, F.~Giavazzi, and A.~Miano (2018).
\newblock Is it the ``how" or the ``when" that matters in fiscal adjustments?
\newblock IMF Economic Review 66(1), 144--188.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Barbiero, Favero, Giavazzi, and
  Paradisi}{Alesina et~al.}{2015}]{Alesina2015}
Alesina, A., O.~Barbiero, C.~Favero, F.~Giavazzi, and M.~Paradisi (2015).
\newblock Austerity in 2009-13.
\newblock {\em Economic Policy\/}~{\em 30\/}(83), 383--437.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Barbiero, Favero, Giavazzi, and
  Paradisi}{Alesina et~al.}{2017}]{Alesina2017}
Alesina, A., O.~Barbiero, C.~Favero, F.~Giavazzi, and M.~Paradisi (2017, May).
\newblock The effects of fiscal consolidations: Theory and evidence.
\newblock Working Paper 23385, National Bureau of Economic Research.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Carloni, and Lecce}{Alesina
  et~al.}{2012}]{Alesina2012b}
Alesina, A., D.~Carloni, and G.~Lecce (2013).
\newblock The electoral consequences of large fiscal adjustments.
\newblock In A.~Alesina and F.~Giavazzi (Eds.), {\em Fiscal Policy after the
  Financial Crisis}, pp.\  531--570. National Bureau of Economic
  Research.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina and Drazen}{Alesina and
  Drazen}{1991}]{Alesina1991}
Alesina, A. and A.~Drazen (1991).
\newblock Why are stabilizations delayed?
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 81\/}(5), 1170--1188.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Favero, and Giavazzi}{Alesina, Favero, and Giavazzi}{2015}]{Alesina2015}
Alesina, A., C. Favero, and F. Giavazzi (2015). The output effect of fiscal
consolidation plans. \textit{Journal of International Economics 96}, 519--542.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Glaeser, and Sacerdote}{Alesina
  et~al.}{2005}]{Alesina2005}
Alesina, A., E.~Glaeser, and B.~Sacerdote (2005).
\newblock Work and leisure in the United States and Europe: Why so different?
\newblock {\em NBER Macroeconomics Annual\/}~{\em 20}, 1--64.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina and Passalacqua}{Alesina and
  Passalacqua}{2016}]{Alesina2016}
Alesina, A. and A.~Passalacqua (2016).
\newblock The political economy of government debt.
\newblock In J.~B. Taylor and H.~Uhlig (Eds.), {\em Handbook of
  Macroeconomics}, Volume~2, pp.\  2599--2651. Elsevier.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina and Perotti}{Alesina and
  Perotti}{1996}]{Alesina1996}
Alesina, A. and R.~Perotti (1997a).
\newblock Fiscal adjustments in OECD countries: \text{Composition} and macroeconomic
  effects.
\newblock IMF Staff Papers 44, 210--248.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina and Perotti}{Alesina and
  Perotti}{1997}]{Alesina1997}
Alesina, A. and R.~Perotti (1997).
\newblock The welfare state and competitiveness.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 87\/}(5), 921--939.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alesina, Perotti, Tavares, Obstfeld, and
  Eichengreen}{Alesina et~al.}{1998}]{Alesina1998}
Alesina, A., R.~Perotti, J.~Tavares, M.~Obstfeld, and B.~Eichengreen (1998).
\newblock The political economy of fiscal adjustments.
\newblock {\em Brookings Papers on Economic Activity\/}~{\em 1998\/}(1),\break 197--266.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Ardagna and Caselli}{Ardagna and
  Caselli}{2014}]{Ardagna2014}
Ardagna, S. and F.~Caselli (2014).
\newblock The political economy of the Greek debt crisis: A tale of two
  bailouts.
\newblock {\em American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics\/}~{\em 6\/}(4),
  291--323.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Auerbach and Gorodnichenko}{Auerbach and
  Gorodnichenko}{2012b}]{Auerbach2012a}
Auerbach, A.~J. and Y.~Gorodnichenko (2012).
\newblock Measuring the output responses to fiscal policy.
\newblock {\em American Economic Journal: Economic Policy\/}~{\em 4\/}(2),
  1--27.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Auerbach and Gorodnichenko}{Auerbach and
  Gorodnichenko}{2012a}]{Auerbach2012}
Auerbach, A.~J. and Y.~Gorodnichenko (2013a).
\newblock Fiscal multipliers in recession and expansion.
\newblock In {\em Fiscal Policy after the Financial Crisis},
  pp.\  63--98. National Bureau of Economic Research.  

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Auerbach and Gorodnichenko}{Auerbach and
  Gorodnichenko}{2013}]{Auerbach2013}
Auerbach, A.~J. and Y.~Gorodnichenko (2013b).
\newblock Output spillovers from fiscal policy.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 103\/}(3), 141--146.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Banks}{Banks}{2004}]{Banks2004}
Banks, G. (2004).
\newblock Structural reform Australian-style: Lessons for others?
\newblock Technical report, Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Barnichon and Matthes}{Barnichon and
  Matthes}{2015}]{Barnichon2015}
Barnichon, R. and C.~Matthes (2015, May).
\newblock Stimulus versus austerity: The asymmetric government spending
  multiplier.
\newblock CEPR Discussion Paper 10584.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Baron and Ferejohn}{Baron and
  Ferejohn}{1989}]{Baron1989}
Baron, D.~P. and J.~A. Ferejohn (1989).
\newblock Bargaining in legislatures.
\newblock {\em The American Political Science Review\/}~{\em 83\/}(4),
  1181--1206.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Barro}{Barro}{1981}]{Barro1981}
Barro, R.~J. (1981, December).
\newblock Output effects of government purchases.
\newblock {\em Journal of Political Economy\/}~{\em 89\/}(6), 1086--1121.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Barro}{Barro}{1984}]{Barro1984}
Barro, R.~J. (1984).
\newblock {\em Macroeconomics}.
\newblock Wiley. 2

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Barro}{Barro}{2001}]{Barro2001}
Barro, R.~J. (2001).
\newblock Economic growth in East Asia before and after the financial crisis.
\newblock Working paper 8330, National Bureau of Economic Research.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Barro and Redlick}{Barro and
  Redlick}{2011}]{Barro2011}
Barro, R.~J. and C.~J. Redlick (2011).
\newblock Macroeconomic effects from government purchases and taxes.
\newblock {\em The Quarterly Journal of Economics\/}~{\em 126\/}(1), 51--102.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Battaglini and Coate}{Battaglini and
  Coate}{2008}]{Battaglini2008}
Battaglini, M. and S.~Coate (2008, March).
\newblock A dynamic theory of public spending, taxation, and debt.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 98\/}(1), 201--236.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Baxter and King}{Baxter and
  King}{1993}]{Baxter1993}
Baxter, M. and R.~G. King (1993, June).
\newblock Fiscal policy in general equilibrium.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 83\/}(3), 315--334.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Ben~Zeev and Pappa}{Ben~Zeev and
  Pappa}{2015}]{BenZeev2015}
Ben~Zeev, N. and E.~Pappa (2015).
\newblock Multipliers of unexpected increases in defense spending: An empirical
  investigation.
\newblock {\em Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control\/}~{\em 57\/}(C),
  205--226.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Bick, Bruggemann, and Fuchs-Schundeln}{Bick
  et~al.}{2016}]{Bick2016}
Bick, A., B.~Bruggemann, and N.~Fuchs-Schundeln (2016).
\newblock Hours worked in Europe and the US: New data, new answers.
\newblock IZA Discussion Paper 10179, Institute for the Study of Labor (IZA).

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Blanchard}{Blanchard}{1990}]{Blanchard1990}
Blanchard, O. J. (1990). Comments on Giavazzi and Pagano. NBER Chapters in
NBER \textit{Macroeconomics Annual }1990, Vol. 5.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Blanchard and Leigh}{Blanchard and
  Leigh}{2014}]{Blanchard2014}
Blanchard, O.~J. and D.~Leigh (2014, June).
\newblock Learning about fiscal multipliers from growth forecast errors.
\newblock {\em IMF Economic Review\/}~{\em 62\/}(2), 179--212.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Blanchard and Perotti}{Blanchard and
  Perotti}{2002}]{Blanchard2002}
Blanchard, O.~J. and R.~Perotti (2002).
\newblock An empirical characterization of the dynamic effects of changes in
  government spending and taxes on output.
\newblock {\em The Quarterly Journal of Economics\/}~{\em 117\/}(4),
  1329--1368.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Blanchard and Watson}{Blanchard and
  Watson}{1986}]{Blanchard1986}
Blanchard, O.~J. and M.~Watson (1986).
\newblock Are business cycles all alike?
\newblock In R.~J. Gordon (Ed.), {\em The American Business Cycle: Continuity
  and Change}, pp.\  123--156. Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Bloom}{Bloom}{2009}]{Bloom2009}
Bloom, N. (2009, 05).
\newblock The impact of uncertainty shocks.
\newblock {\em Econometrica\/}~{\em 77\/}(3), 623--685.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Blundell, Bozio, and Laroque}{Blundell
  et~al.}{2011}]{Blundell2011}
Blundell, R., A.~Bozio, and G.~Laroque (2011, May).
\newblock Labor supply and the extensive margin.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 101\/}(3), 482--486.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Bohn}{Bohn}{1991}]{Bohn1991}
Bohn, H. (1991).
\newblock Budget balance through revenue or spending adjustments?
\newblock {\em Journal of Monetary Economics\/}~{\em 27\/}(3), 333--359.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Brender and Drazen}{Brender and
  Drazen}{2008}]{Brender2008}
Brender, A. and A.~Drazen (2008, December).
\newblock How do budget deficits and economic growth affect reelection
  prospects? Evidence from a large panel of countries.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 98\/}(5), 2203--2220.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Buchanan and Wagner}{Buchanan and
  Wagner}{1977}]{Buchanan1977}
Buchanan, J.~M. and R.~E. Wagner (1977).
\newblock {\em Democracy in Deficit: The Political Legacy of Lord Keynes}.
\newblock New York: Academic Press.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Burnside, Eichenbaum, and Fisher}{Burnside
  et~al.}{2004}]{Burnside2004}
Burnside, C., M.~Eichenbaum, and J.~D.~M. Fisher (2004, March).
\newblock Fiscal shocks and their consequences.
\newblock {\em Journal of Economic Theory\/}~{\em 115\/}(1), 89--117.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Caggiano, Castelnuovo, Colombo, and
  Nodari}{Caggiano et~al.}{2015}]{Caggiano2015}
Caggiano, G., E.~Castelnuovo, V.~Colombo, and G.~Nodari (2015).
Estimating~\text{fiscal} multipliers: News from a non-linear world.
{\em The Economic Journal\/}~{\em 125\/}(584), 746--776.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Cairns}{Cairns}{1994}]{Cairns1994}
Cairns, A.~C. (1994).
\newblock An election to be remembered: Canada 1993.
\newblock {\em Canadian Public Policy/Analyse de Politiques 20(3)}, 219--234.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Caldara and Kamps}{Caldara and
  Kamps}{2017}]{Caldara2017}
Caldara, D. and C.~Kamps (2017).
\newblock The analytics of SVARS: A unified framework to measure fiscal
  multipliers.
\newblock {\em Review of Economic Studies\/} 84(3), 1015--1040.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Caminada and Goudswaard}{Caminada and
  Goudswaard}{2009}]{Caminada2009}
Caminada, K. and K.~Goudswaard (2009).
\newblock Effectiveness of poverty reduction in the EU: A descriptive analysis.
\newblock {\em Poverty \& Public Policy\/}~{\em 1\/}(2), 1--49.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Cavallo}{Cavallo}{2005}]{Cavallo2005}
Cavallo, M. (2005).
\newblock Government employment expenditure and the effects of fiscal policy
  shocks.
\newblock Federal Reserve Bank of San Francisco Working Paper~16,
  2005.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Chang, Kim, Kwon, and Rogerson}{Chang
  et~al.}{2011}]{Chang2011}
Chang, Y., S.-B. Kim, K.~Kwon, and R.~Rogerson (2011, May).
\newblock Interpreting labor supply regressions in a model of full- and
  part-time work.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 101\/}(3), 476--481.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Chetty, Guren, Manoli, and Weber}{Chetty
  et~al.}{2011}]{Chetty2011}
Chetty, R., A.~Guren, D.~Manoli, and A.~Weber (2011, May).
\newblock Are micro and macro labor supply elasticities consistent? A review of
  evidence on the intensive and extensive margins.
\newblock {\em American Economic Review\/}~{\em 101\/}(3), 471--475.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Chodorow-Reich}{Chodorow-Reich}{2017}]{Chodorow-Reich2017}
Chodorow-Reich, G. (2017). Geographic cross-section fiscal spending
multipliers: What have we learned? Working paper 23577. National Bureau of
Economic Research.


\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Chodorow-Reich, Feiveson, Liscow, and
  Woolston}{Chodorow-Reich et~al.}{2012}]{Chodorow-Reich2012}
Chodorow-Reich, G., L.~Feiveson, Z.~Liscow, and W.~G. Woolston (2012, April).
\newblock Does state fiscal relief during recessions increase employment?
  Evidence from the American Recovery and Reinvestment Act.
\newblock {\em American Economic Journal: Economic Policy\/}~{\em 4\/}(3),\break
  118--145.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Christiano, Eichenbaum, and Rebelo}{Christiano
  et~al.}{2011}]{Christiano2011}
Christiano, L., M.~Eichenbaum, and S.~Rebelo (2011).
\newblock When is the government spending multiplier large?
\newblock {\em Journal of Political Economy\/}~{\em 119\/}(1), 78--121.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the last entry, then its working fine, please suggest what I did as wrong? Please excuse me if the error is silly....

Note that I'm using MikTeX v2.9 on a Windows system....

Comment: For me, the code above compiles without an error

Comment: the posted code makes no error but a warning `Package natbib Warning: There were multiply defined citations.` But the example is not at all reasonable to post here you should make a _minimal_ example that makes the error you want to ask about and remove every other citation  and package not relevant to the question

Comment: your usage of `\cite...` within `\bibitem` doesn't generate an error but it is very weird.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - It looks like the OP uses a bibliography style that's only marginally compatible with the `natbib` citation management package. For sure, natbib's own bib style files would generate `[Ahmed and Rogers(1995)]`, *not* `[\protect\citeauthoryear{Ahmed and Rogers}{Ahmed and
  Rogers}{1995}]`.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: @Mico I was assuming it was a hand written bibliography, hard to know:-)

Comment: @Mico `\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}` is a valid way to provide the author-year metadata according to `natbib.sty`. So that part of the style would be properly compatible with `natbib`. The earliest use of that idiom on CTAN I could find on a quick search is from https://ctan.org/pkg/newapa

Comment: @moewe - Thanks. Do note that I did not claim that, say, `[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{Jones et al.}{1990}]` was invalid. I only meant to say that it's natbib's way of creating metadata for various possible citation callouts, *given the bib style that's in use*, e.g., `newapa`. FWIW, the bib styles that are distributed with the natbib package itself, as well as the bib styles produced by the `makebst` utility, would generate `[Jones et~al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams]` (since the option `longnamesfirst` has been set). `natbib` would know exactly what to do too.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were using the `\protect\citeauthoryear` as evidence that the style does not work well with `natbib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no error messages, just the following warning messages:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Alesina2015' multiply defined.

...

Package natbib Warning: There were multiply defined citations.

[3] (uu.aux

Package natbib Warning: Citation(s) may have changed.
(natbib)                Rerun to get citations correct.
```

Basically, you have two entries with the same citation key, viz., `Alesina2015`.

How to fix this?

- Open your bib file, find the entries with key `Alesina2015`, and modify one or more of these keys to make them unique. Suppose that the bib file contains exactly two entries with key `Alesina2015`, and suppose that you change the keys to `Alesina2015uu` and `Alesina2015vv`.
- Next, check all `\cite`-like instructions in your tex document(s) that currently mention `Alesina2015`. Determine which ones should point to `Alesina2015a` and which ones should point to `Alesina2015b`, and perform the needed modifications.
- Once the entries in the bib file have been corrected and the arguments of the `\cite` instrutions have been updated, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.
- To verify that the earlier bibliography-related mistakes are gone, open the log file and try to find the string

  ```
  Package natbib Warning: There were multiply defined citations.
  ```

  If no such string can be found, you've successfully fixed the issues.